# Redirecting all .HTML to .PHP pages but not from one directory?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I recently converted all the `.html` pages on my site to `.php`. I added the following code to my `.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)\.htm(l?)$ $1.php
```

This works fine and `.html` pages re-direct to `.php` pages.

My question is, is there any way to limit what files this code affects?

More specifically I would like to stop the `.html` and `.htm` pages from my sub domain from being redirected.

```
shop.domain.com
```

I have other parts of my website in a sub-directory of the root folder that need to end in `.html` and I don't want their `.html` extensions to re-direct.

Is there any code or way to do this?

Comment: .htaccess files only affect the directories for which it is in.

Comment: Then you have more rules that are interfering with each other and you're not showing enough information to deal with it.

Comment: The only other rule in my htacess is: ErrorDocument 404 /404page.php What other files or code should I be on the look out for?

Comment: multiple .htaccess file in other directories

Comment: I found another .htacess file in my shop folder, must have been made by my ecommerce site. It has data in it but I cannot post it as it is too long. Please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^shop\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html?$ $1.php [R=301,NC,L]
```

This won't redirect any sub-directory including `shop`. In case you want to allow that (except `shop`) use

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html?$ $1.php [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: That solved it! Works perfectly. Pages that I want to re-direct do, and pages in the shop folder do not re-direct. Thank you Ravi! And thank you Prix for your efforts! :)